# Query data is received but can not be accessed from GraphQL API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I built the API with apollo server and everything works fine in graphiql. I make requests to the api from front-end react app with apollo client.

```
const [getUserPosts, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USER_POSTS);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfile();
    getUserPosts({ variables: { email: userEmail } });
  }, [userEmail]);
```

SO getUserProfile fetches the user email from the express back end (I have an express serving react and a separate graphql api), then I query the posts of that user on the api. Below is the query itself

```
export const GET_USER_POSTS = gql`
  query User($email: String) {
    user(email: $email) {
      email
      posts {
        content
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is the typedefs and resolver on the api server

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    email: String
    posts: [Post]
  }

  type Post {
    id: ID!
    email: String
    content: String
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User]
    posts: [Post]
    user(email: String): [User]
    post(id: String): [Post]
  }

  type Mutation {
    addPost(email: String, content: String): [Post]
    deletePost(id: String): [Post]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: () => User.find(),
    posts: () => Post.find(),
    user: (parent, args) => User.find({ email: args.email }),
    post: (parent, args) => Post.find({ _id: args.id }),
  },

  User: {
    posts: async user => {
      try {
        const postsByUser = Post.find({ email: user.email });
        return postsByUser;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },

  Mutation: {
    addPost: async (parent, args) => {
      const newPost = new Post({
        email: args.email,
        content: args.content,
      });
      try {
        newPost.save();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },

    deletePost: async (parent, args) => {
      try {
        const deletedPost = await Post.deleteOne({ _id: args.id });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

then I try to `console.log` the data here

```
if (loading) {
    console.log(loading);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  if (data) {
    console.log(loading);
    let test = data.user[0];
    //I can see the data logged in the console as an object {email: "abc", posts: [array of posts]}
    console.log(test); 
  }
```

BUT if I try to `console.log(test.posts)` react results with can not read property "**posts**" of undefined

UPDATE-1 !!
So when react results with the above error, I try to refresh the page again and it now can logs the "posts" array. But it sometimes take 2 or 3 refresh to make it work and sometimes when I refresh again it does not work anymore. Why is this happening ????

UPDATE-2 !!
So I try to troubleshoot with this line:

`{data ? console.log(data.user[0].posts) : console.log("nothing")}`

and interestingly it actually does log "nothing" a few times in the console before logging the data. But this is weird because I explicitly write that if only "data" is "true" then log it in the console. But somehow "data" is somtimes `null` itself. This `data` is provided by apollo client and it should be always `true` after `loading` is false, how is `data` still `null` after `loading` is `false` already ???

Comment: `id` fields queried [in types/on user 'level', on posts child level]? types defs? sample response?

Comment: Hello, I just updated with the typedefs and resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. Turns out it actually comes from within this block:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfile();
    getUserPosts({ variables: { email: userEmail } });
  }, [userEmail]);
```

After observing in the network tab, it seems that my app try to send request to graphQL api before `getUserProfile` was done pulling user email, so it sent an empty request and hence received nothing. I was naive to think `getUserProfile` and `getUserPosts` will be executed synchronously. So I wrap `getUserPosts` with

```
if (userEmail) {
      getUserPosts({ variables: { email: userEmail } });
    }
```

So now only after I received the `uerEmail` then `getUserPosts` will be executed.

Comment: you can use `skip` option instead of lazy